# How to specify different action for link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I'm creating a website where users can mark and unmark items as "favorite".
I implemented this via Ajax using Rails' form attribute `remote: true` so whole page does not reloaded, just status of item is changed.

I have two methods in `FavouritesController`

```
def create
    Favourite.create!(item_id: params[:favourite][:item_id])    
    respond_to { |format| format.js }
end

def destroy
    Favourite.find(params[:id]).destroy!
    respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

The problem is:

I want to call another action from the same controller to "unmark" item in another view. I use code below but when I click on link - old method `destroy` is called from controller, instead of desired `delete_from_index_list` method. 
I need two separate methods because they returns different javascript (jquery).

```
<%= link_to "delete", @favourite, method: :delete, remote: true, action: 'delete_from_index_list'  %>
```

Comment: The second argument should be a URL helper that leads to your action in your controller: the pattern is: `my_action_my_controller_path(extra_param: value)`, so in your case: `link_to "Delete", delete_from_index_list_favourite_path(id: @favourite.id)` (you might have to pluralize the "favourite" depending on if you defined delete_from_index_list as a member or collection path of the Favourite resources).

Comment: Thanks, MrYoshiji. Is this route semantically correct? `match '/favourites/delete/:id' => 'favourites#delete_from_favourites_list',
                                     as: :delete_from_favourites_list_favourite,
                                     via: 'delete'`  Maybe I should use `match '/favourites/:id/delete'` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the link_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) - I this will describe what you want.

I haven't tested this, but I'm guessing you want:

```
<%= link_to "delete", controller: 'favourites', action: 'delete_from_index_list', id: @favourite, remote: true %>
```

If it were my code, I would find the route for the `delete_from_index_list` method, and call it this way:

```
<%= link_to "delete", route_for_delete_from_index_list_path(@favourite), method: :delete %>
```

This way it's more resourceful, whereas the former example is non-resourceful.